# CMake 3.17 deletes Qt translations when updating the TS files

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

**Update: Simplified problem**

With CMake 3.16.8 or less, the following workflow was working, but 3.17+ deletes the Qt's TS files.
The idea is taken from [Professional CMake, 7th Edition by Craig Scott](https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/)

### Requirements

cmake 3.17+, Qt 5.9+, ninja

### Concept

To update the translation files for Qt, `UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS` can be enabled. When finished, disable it.
CMake 3.17+ deletes the updated TS files.

Adjust pathes in the script `update_translation.sh` to automate the workflow.

### Steps to reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/Macintron/QtTranslationDemo.git # or create files from below in QtTranslationDemo.
mkdir build  # NOT in QtTranslationDemo
cd build
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=[pathToQtDir/5.15.1/clang_64] ../QtTranslationDemo
ninja
./demo
```

Output should be:

```
Demo
de.qm: 85 bytes
  Language: 'Deutsch'
  greeting: ''
en.qm: 85 bytes
  Language: 'English'
  greeting: ''
```

now the problem starts:

```
cmake -DUPDATE_TRANSLATIONS=ON ../QtTranslationDemo
ninja demoTranslations
cmake -DUPDATE_TRANSLATIONS=OFF ../QtTranslationDemo
# new strings ("greeting") should haven been added to the ts files, but TS files are deleted instead!
```

Why are the TS files get deleted? Is this a bug in CMake 3.17+ or a bug in my workflow?

### build info

The build directory must NOT be inside the sources.

### Source files

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(QtTranslationDemo LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt5
  COMPONENTS
    LinguistTools Core
  REQUIRED
)

option(UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS "Enable rescanning sources to update .ts files" OFF)


set(_tsFiles en.ts de.ts)
if(UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS)
  message("** parse sources for new translations")
  qt5_create_translation(_qmFiles
    main.cpp
    ${_tsFiles}
  )
else()
  message("** update qm files")
  qt5_add_translation(_qmFiles
    ${_tsFiles}
  )
endif()

add_custom_target(demoTranslations DEPENDS ${_qmFiles})


add_executable(demo
  main.cpp
  ${_qmFiles}
)

target_link_libraries(demo
  PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QDir>
#include <QStringList>


static const char* language = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("@default", "Language");
static const char* greeting = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("@default", "greeting"); // not in ts files now!


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  qDebug("Demo");
  QStringList qms = QDir("./").entryList({"*.qm"});
  for (const auto& qm: qms) {
    qDebug("%s: %lld bytes", qPrintable(qm), QFileInfo("./" + qm).size());
    QTranslator appTranslator;
    if (appTranslator.load(qm, "./")) {
      qDebug("  Language: '%s'", qPrintable(appTranslator.translate("@default", language)));
      qDebug("  greeting: '%s'", qPrintable(appTranslator.translate("@default", greeting)));
    } else {
        qWarning("Failed to load %s", qPrintable(qm));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**en.ts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="en" sourcelanguage="en">
<context>
    <name>@default</name>
    <message>
        <source>Language</source>
        <translation>English</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

**de.ts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de" sourcelanguage="en">
<context>
    <name>@default</name>
    <message>
        <source>Language</source>
        <translation>Deutsch</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

**update_translation.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
thisdir=$(dirname $0)

qt_root=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt5.15/5.15.1/clang_64

#cmaketool=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.8/bin/cmake
cmaketool=cmake


# easier setup
rm -Rf en.qm de.qm CMakeFiles CMakeCache.txt cmake_install.cmake build.ninja .ninja_* > /dev/null 2>&1
git checkout $thisdir/de.ts $thisdir/en.ts  # restore files
$cmaketool --version
$cmaketool -G Ninja -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$qt_root ../QtTranslationDemo
ninja
./demo
rm -f demo

echo "Starting CMake with DUPDATE_TRANSLATIONS..."
$cmaketool -DUPDATE_TRANSLATIONS=ON $thisdir

echo
echo "Updating translation files..."
ninja demoTranslations

echo
echo "Restore CMake configuration..."
$cmaketool -DUPDATE_TRANSLATIONS=OFF $thisdir

ninja
./demo

exit 0
```

Comment: This looks still a bit like there is code that is not really needed to produce there error. Please further minimize the example while keeping the error as much as possible. [example]

Comment: @Trilarion The sample has been minimized.

Comment: Thanks for improving the question. It might also make sense to post this question/problem on the issue tracker of CMake (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues). I have made good experience, they react quite fast and if you are sure that it works with CMake 3.16 but doesn't with 3.17 that might give them a clue what is wrong. Might even be something with CMake.

Comment: Because I already started here, I didn't want to open an issue at kitware with the same problem. Issue created: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21549

Comment: You didn't get an answer here for some days so that is reasonable. Please don't forget, should you get an answer at either of the two places, let the other place also know.

Answer (score 0):

This was a generic CMake problem, caused by the cleandead feature. It should be fixed in CMake 3.19.2.
Thank you all for your contributions to solve the problem.